# How to show that the limit exists?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

the limit of $$f(x,y) = \frac{x}{\sqrt y}$$
as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$?

I have approached the origin via different paths and have come to the conclusion that the limit exists.
I just cant prove it.

Could someone give me a nudge. Not the answer.

Comment: Letting $x=\sqrt{y}$ and $x=2\sqrt{y}$ will generate two different limits so it does not exist.

Comment: Now I feel silly, I have spent an hour trying to prove that it does exists using the epsilon delta method... thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't exist. Consider e.g. $(x_n, y_n)=(0, 1/n)$ and $(x_n, y_n)=(1/n, 1/n^2)$.

Comment: Thanks fellow numbersmith :)

Answer (score 2):

Take
$$
r_n = (x_n, y_n) = (c/n, 1/n^2) \quad (c \in \mathbb{R})
$$
then 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} r_n = 0
$$
and
$$
f(r_n) = \frac{c}{n}\frac{\sqrt{n^2}}{1} = c
$$
so you can achieve any real value
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f(r_n) = c
$$
depending on your approach towards $0$. To have "a limit" requires uniqueness.

Comment: Showing one path gives one limit is not enough in multivariable calculus. It must exist for each possible path (and be the same for them all).

Comment: This doesn't warrant a down vote, in my opinion. This user chose to give one of the non-obvious (if there is such a thing here) sublimits, one of the obvious one being something like the one along $t\mapsto (0,t)$.

Comment: I agree with you. I wasn't the guy to give the down vote either. Although I can understand if that is what it looked like.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to highlight is for a multivariate limit to exist it must exist & be the same for all possible paths. Other people have already shown why that is not the case for this particular fun.

Comment: Not sure what your answer brings to the table compared to the other answers...